# How to create an os.exec Command struct from a string with spaces

Tags: go

I want my method to receive a command to exec as a string. If the input string has spaces, how do I split it into cmd, args for os.exec?

The documentation says to create my Exec.Cmd struct like

```
cmd := exec.Command("tr", "a-z", "A-Z")
```

This works fine:

```
a := string("ifconfig")
cmd := exec.Command(a)
output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
fmt.Println(output) // prints ifconfig output
```

This fails:

```
a := string("ifconfig -a")
cmd := exec.Command(a)
output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
fmt.Println(output) // 'ifconfig -a' not found
```

I tried strings.Split(a), but receive an error message: cannot use (type []string) as type string in argument to exec.Command

Comment: your using strings.Split() incorrectly golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split you need to supply a separator. so.. strings.Split(a, " ") to split on a single space, secondly, you can't split a slice because it is already split, so your variable "a" is already a slice, not a string. Lastly you could also define your slice instead of splitting the string. a := []string{"inconfig", "a"}.

Comment: won't this break if an argument contains a space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please, check out:
https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Cmd_CombinedOutput

Your code fails because *exec.Command* expects command arguments to be separated from actual *command name*.

*strings.Split* signature (https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split):

```
func Split(s, sep string) []string
```

What you tried to achieve:

```
command := strings.Split("ifconfig -a", " ")
if len(command) < 2 {
    // TODO: handle error
}
cmd := exec.Command(command[0], command[1:]...)
stdoutStderr, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    // TODO: handle error more gracefully
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// do something with output
fmt.Printf("%s\n", stdoutStderr)
```

Comment: @kostix No, it won't work. Documentation says: `func Command(name string, arg ...string) *Cmd` - therefore you literally must pass first argument (command name) separately. Otherwise, you would produce error: `not enough arguments in call to exec.Command`. I pointed it out under @Mark answer as he made the same mistake.

Answer (score 17):

```
args := strings.Fields("ifconfig  -a ")
exec.Command(args[0], args[1:]...)
```

[strings.Fields()](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields) splits on whitespace, and returns a slice

`...` expands slice into individual string arguments

Comment: This is not a universal solution and will fail if an argument itself contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the `exec.Command()` like this:

```golang
args=[]string{
  "-l",
  fmt.Sprintf(xxxxx),
}
cmd := exec.Command("ls", args...)
cmd.Stdout = os.Stderr
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain why?

Comment: When the argument list is long, I can check the arguments easily in this way.